# in Telegram OnCallbackQuery return InlineKeyboard

Tags: c#, telegram

I wrote a telegram bot ,I need when click on InlineKeyboard button on callbackquery event
I return list of inline buttons ,but it seems doesn't work.
Thanks for any guides.

Best Regards
Alireza

Answer (score 0):

Only inline query can return inline buttons, but you can [editMessageReplyMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) when you received callback query.

Comment: thanks Sean for your attentions ,I want to return inline button list ,but only return message and don't return inline button Lists

Answer (score 0):

It resolved .the problem was in callback param that shouldn't be empty.
Regards
Ali